# jquery.validation.js min and max value from another input textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am using jquery.validate.js to validate my asp.net form, I want to give MAX validation value from one of the textbox in the form, My attempt as below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RPriceTextBox" runat="server" class="{min:0.01, max:<%= OPriceTextBox.Text%>}" />
```

or I tried as :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RPriceTextBox" runat="server" class="{min:0.01, max:'#ctl00_MainContent_OPriceTextBox.value'}" />
```

It is not working and I am getting "max" validation value as NaN.

Comment: So that means its expecting an number as input, and your not passing an number. Try logging the  variables separately too see what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<form name="myForm">
<fieldset>
<legend>My Form</legend>
<label for='number'>Number</label>
<input name='number' id="num" />
<label for='change-range'>Max range</label>
<input name='change-range' id="mx" value="5" />
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" />
</form>


$(document).ready(function(){
var mx = parseInt($("#mx").val());
alert(mx);
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        number: {required: true, min: 1, max: mx}
    }
});
});
```

Enjoy http://jsfiddle.net/qC2Ya/75/